# paypal payments pro test credit cards fail

Tags: c#, paypal

Trying to use PayPal Payments Pro with hosted pages to accept credit cards on a web site. I'm having trouble getting the test credit cards to work, they all give the error:

Declined: 10544-Please use a different payment card.

I'm not using a shopping cart or making direct API calls, I am testing with the paypal payments pro asp.net c# sample from paypal, it does this:

posts my credentials to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com and gets a secure token then posts secure token to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com to display checkout page

When I enter visa test 4111111111111111 exp 12/19 or any other test credit card I get the above error.

In the sandbox the are no transactions recorded.

What I have done, following the documentation:

I have a paypal payments pro account with the following settings:

PayPal Payments Pro Live

Hosted Checkout Pages   Live

Payflow SDK/API (Full Access)   Live

Paypal Express Checkout Live

I linked my business paypal account with manager.paypal.com

I upgraded a sandbox account on developer.paypal.com - there were two already there, a business and a personal, I upgraded the business sandbox account to Business Pro which I believe then links it to my payments pro account(?).

Setup hosted pages in manager.paypal.com per documentation, set use secure token to yes.

Set site to live - I did this because I am posting to 'pilot-' urls.  I had it on test (which means you can use the normal urls) but due to the error and a post I read I set the site to live and used pilot, no change.

So everything seems to be working except the test numbers are supposed to succeed so I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: Hi KPG, Try to use different test credit card number. Refer the below links for test credit cards used for sandbox mode: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm
http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/

Comment: I think the problem is that since I am using PayPal as the processor I can't use the test CC numbers...I read at developers.paypal.com that when testing for a processor other than PayPal to us the test numbers, to me this implies that with PayPal in test mode to use a valid card?  I tried a valid card and it succeeded in test mode.  A live PayPal support rep did not know why the test card failed and escalated the ticket.

Comment: Murugesh - I tried a handful of the test numbers - same 10544 error each time,

Answer (score 0):

KPG,

PayPal will change its processes every now and then, but here is the current process for sandbox credit cards:

1. Log into your developer account
2. Scroll down the left-hand vertical menu until you see the "Mock" section.

If you don't immediately see this vertical menu, navigate to your "dashboard" first. It will be there.

3. Click on "Credit Card Generator". Here is text from that page:

> Generate random credit cards for testing purposes. You can add credit cards to a Sandbox PayPal account or use them for credit card payments.

4. Click "Generate" for all parts of the CC number, including CVC.